# What does parameters mean for GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Why do we pass `0` as first two parameters in  `GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)` ? What does it signify?

Comment: Looking at your recent questions, you should probably find an OpenGL ES tutorial and work through it, rather than asking about individual concepts on stackoverflow.  Google search finds several; perhaps http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the spec, it explains it all: [Opengl spec](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml).

The parameters `x,y,width,height` basically define a rectangle on the window with the OpenGL context that you want to use for OpenGL. It's typically the whole window but it doesn't have to be.

`x,y` is basically the bottom left coordinate of your rectangle.

**Edit:** you could draw an entire scene in the top half of your screen, change the viewport to the bottom half rectangle, then another scene in the bottom half or a different view of the first.

Comment: I would add to this, that the viewport is actually part of the vertex transformation process. It is tempting to think that of it as a rectangle that you are allowed to draw into, but what it really does is map the corners of NDC space (after vertices are projected into clip-space and perspective divided) to 4 points in window-space. You can see this in action if you ever call `glViewport (...)` using dimensions smaller than the framebuffer, followed by `glClear (...)` - the entire framebuffer will be cleared because that does not involve any vertex transformation..

Comment: You can still affect parts outside the viewport with commands that do not use vertex transformation. In modern GL, there are very few such commands. `glBlitFramebuffer (...)` (not even part of ES 2.0) and `glClear (...)` are the only things that come to mind immediately.